# Laravel does not show images on production server

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

my production server is ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and I have laravel 5.5
In the route:

> /var/www/forumb

my public folder is in the directory:

> /var/www/forumb/public

users upload images and these are saved in:

> /var/www/forumb/public/uploads/images

the images folder has 777 permissions
in the images folder there are images that use the cover
and these are shown normal from the views

the problem is that the images that upload the users are not seen from the views and these are in the same folder images

the cover images I can see directly from the browser like this:

> http://forumb.com/uploads/images/banner1.jpeg

the user images

> http://forumb.com/uploads/images/5fa7385e1542a31ab9c34419b4d914fe81a11449.jpeg

but these can not be seen, laravel returns 404 error

the only images that can be seen from the views are the ones that came up together with the framework and that are in the images folder

all the others can not be seen until I uploaded an image from filezilla to the server but can not see either

this only happens on the production server, on my localhost everything works normal

this is mi code in the view

```
<img class="card-img-top border-bot" src="{{ !is_null(user()->image) ? $profile_image : '/uploads/images/facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg' }}" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="{!! user()->nombre_empresa !!}">
```

this my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $perPage = 6;
    $page = input('page', 1);
    $baseUrl = config('app.url') . '/news-and-events';
    $items = News::whereHas('photos')->with('photos')->active()->orderBy('active_from', 'DESC')->select('news.*')->get();
    $profile_image = profile_image();
    $total = $items->count();

    // paginator
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(),
        $perPage, $page, ['path' => $baseUrl, 'originalEntries' => $total]);

    // if pagination ajax
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(view('website.news_events.pagination')
            ->with('paginator', $paginator)
            ->render());
    }

    return $this->view('news_events.news_events')->with('paginator', $paginator)->with('profile_image', $profile_image);
}
```

profile_image() function

```
function profile_image()
{
    $image = user()->image;
    $gender = user()->gender;
    if ($image && strlen($image) > 5) {
        return '/uploads/images/' . $image;
    }
    else {
        return "/images/admin/$gender.png";
    }
}
```

the images are uploaded normally but not shown

Comment: Please post your controller function which handles the upload.

Comment: Can you verify, by looking at the filesystem in your hosting, where the files actually end up? Are you sure you're saving the images in `public/uploads/images` and not somewhere in the storage folder?

Comment: if I'm sure because I can see from the terminal that the files that users upload are in the images folder

Comment: show us your `<img src="` usage.

Comment: Did you try replacing relative path to absolute with `asset` helper?

Comment: yes but it did not work either

Comment: Just check the image path manually by copying from `src""` to your browser and see that either `image issue` or `url issue`.

Comment: if I did that but it only works with the images that I upload together with the framework but not with the new images that users upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you save an uploaded file to disk, Laravel puts the file in `storage/app/public` and not in `public`. So, you need to create a symbolic link to have access to these files from the web.

> the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in  `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: I already tried that but I tried again I get this: The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Comment: Do you get any error or something? I'm pretty sure this solution works.

Comment: no, I do not have any error message, only a white box is shown

Comment: Do you see a white box when you're uploading the image or when you're trying to display it? What exactly HTML Laravel generates for the image? Please show the code you use to store the image.

Comment: a white box is shown in the place where the user image should be
This is very strange and I do not think it's by code since I'm using the Adminlte templates but I'll upload the code anyway

Comment: but in production we can't run the commands like in cpanel, what to do then?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not seeing images in production is well explained by @Alexey Mezenin, in reply to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48334845/7719176),

in short **in laravel you have to create link to your storage folder in public folder using command** `php artisan storage:link` then you can see images,

But the problem in production is we can not run commands directly, but we can run it programmatically,

So edit your `routes/web.php` file and add below lines:

```
Route::get('/any-route', function () {
  Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

**imp note:** keep in mind that **if you have ran that command locally, then the storage folder  is already there in public folder, so first you have to delete the `public/storage` folder**,

and then you can run that specified route `/any-route` stated as in above route file.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer from this issue too. On my localhost I could upload and view images. On the server, i could upload images but can't view images on my browsers though i can see the image in public/storage. I later discover i was pointing to the image wrongly. I hope what worked for me will work for you. These are what i did.

1. Upload project to server. In my case it was

   `|-www
   |--laravelProject`
2. Run `$ php artisan storage:link` or run this script

   `$exitCode = Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );
   echo $exitCode; // 0 exit code for no errors.`
3. I upload my image

   ```
   $file = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('my_image'));
   $baseUrl = url('/');
   $imagePath = $baseUrl.'/laravelProject/public/storage/'.$file;
   $input['image_path'] = $imagePath;
   $input['image_root'] = $file; //used when deleting
   MobileSlider::create($input);
   ```
4. I confirm that my image is at

> www/laravelProject/public/storage/images

yours could be

> public_html/laravelProject/public/storage/images

5. To access the image on my browser

> http://yoursite.com/laravelProject/public/storage/images/dfdbfdbfdfdhfkhdfhnduok.png

I am not sure this is the best way, but it worked for me.